# range based on date when not within a month doesn't work (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I want to find out files that are older than x days (**time and weekends** don't count for the purpose of calculating a **file's age**). I need to use only weekdays.

My script is working but only if the date from the range are within the same month. Otherwise the range size is 0.

I run the script via ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]

```
Dir['*.gdb'].each { |db|
  puts db
  puts ((Date.strptime(File.mtime(db).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))..(Date.today)).select {|d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size

}
```

any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: Should public holidays be counted?

Comment: @Lars Haugseth: it doesn't matter in that case

Comment: not sure what happened but `puts ((Date.strptime(File.mtime(db).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))..(Date.today)).select {|d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size` is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the final code that deletes all files from

- settings['path']
- that are older than settings['days'] - weekend days are not counted
- and are not in settings['exclude'] array

-

```
require 'date'

  settings = {
    'radek' => { 'path' => '/var/lib/firebird/data/radek*.gdb','days' => '3','exclude'=>['radek_rft.gdb','radek_tmp.gdb','radek_test.gdb','radek_cmapping.gdb'] }
  }

  settings.each_value { |user|
    user['exclude'].collect! {|file| file.downcase }
    Dir[user['path']].each { |db|
      old = ( (Date.strptime(File.mtime(db).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))..(Date.today)).select {|d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size - 1
      if (old.to_i >= user['days'].to_i) and not(user['exclude'].include?(File.basename(db))) then output=  %x[rm #{db}]   end
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To find files older than X days eg 7 days

```
x=7 
t=Time.now
days=t - (x * 86400)
Dir["*.gdb"].each do |db|
  if File.mtime(db)  < days
     puts db
  end
end
```

To exclude weekends

```
t=Time.now  # get current date 
days=t - (7 * 86400)  # get date 7 days before
Dir["*.gdb"].each do |db| 
  wd=File.mtime(db).wday    # get the wday of file. 1 (monday), ... 5 (friday)
  if File.mtime(db)  < days and wd.between?(1,5)
     # File.mtime(db)  < days means get files older than 7 days
     # at the same time check the wday of the file whether they are in 1..5 range
     # using wd.between?(1,5)
     puts db
  end
end
```

Comment: @ghostdog74: I am trying to understand your code and I cannot grasp how you exclude the weekends. Exclude weekends means not to count weekend in the calculation not to exclude if I run the script on weekend.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. My code gets ALL files that are more than 7 days old AND at the same time, their wday all falls in the range 1..5. That's it.

Comment: I think Radek means that weekends don't count for the purpose of calculating a file's age — that is, if it's Monday and the file was last edited Friday, it's one day old, not three.

Comment: Oh, i see. then i misinterpreted his question.